# C socket Invalid range header

Tags: c, sockets, http

I'm trying to make a program that serve a file for others to download.
It listens on a port and accept any request and send files through socket.
I'm not worrying about NAT yet.

**The problem I have** is that Downloading that file with aria2c (or wget) gives me "Invalid range header error". However, downloading locally (download from 127.0.0.1) works fine.

Knowing it might cause a problem, I disabled multi-threading download on aria2c by adding `-x1` flag.

What am I doing wrong?

---

The error is:

```
12/23 20:04:07 [ERROR] CUID#8 - Download aborted. URI=http://104.38.127.225:8000
Exception: [AbstractCommand.cc:351] errorCode=8 URI=http://104.38.127.225:8000
  -> [HttpResponse.cc:86] errorCode=8 Invalid range header. Request: 98304-187031/187032, Response: 0-187031/187032
```

---

A bit of explanation on the code:

1. `findFilename` just generate file name from file path
2. `serveFile` opens a socket and listen on it to send anyone that connects to it the specified file

My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <unistd.h> /* for close() */

/* find file name from path */
/* file name have to be shorter than 512 characters*/
/* remember to deallocate memory */
char *findFilename(char *filepath)
{
  size_t pt;
  size_t filenamePt = 0;
  char ch;
  char *filename = (char*) malloc(512);

  for (pt = 0; pt < strlen(filepath); pt++)
  {
    ch = filepath[pt];
    filename[filenamePt] = ch;
    filenamePt++;

    if(ch == '/')
    {
      bzero(filename, 512);
      filenamePt = 0;
    }
  }

  filename[filenamePt + 1] = '\0';

  return filename;
}

int serveFile(char* filepath, int port)
{
  FILE *file;
  char *buffer;
  long int fileLength;
  size_t bufferSize;

  /* get file name */
  char* filename = findFilename(filepath);
  if (!filename)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "file path error\n");
    return -1;
  }



  /* open file */
  file = fopen(filepath, "rb");
  if (!file)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "file open error\n");
    return -1;
  }

  /* get file length */
  fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
  fileLength=ftell(file);
  fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
  bufferSize = fileLength + 1;

  /* allocate memory */
  buffer=(char *)malloc(bufferSize);
  if (!buffer)
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "allocate memory error\n");
      fclose(file);
      return -1;
  }

  /* read file */
  fread(buffer, fileLength, 1, file);
  fclose(file);

  /* compose header */
  char header[1024];

  sprintf(header,
          "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n"
          "Content-Length: %li\n"
          "Accept-Ranges: bytes\n"
          "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"%s\"\n"
          "\n", fileLength, filename);

  /* do not need filename anymore */
  free(filename);

  /* create socket */
  int socketfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  /* configure socket */
  struct sockaddr_in address;

  bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
  address.sin_family = AF_INET;
  address.sin_port = htons(port); /* host to network short */
  address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

  /* bind & listen */
  if(bind(socketfd, (struct sockaddr*) &address, sizeof(address)) != 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "bind error\n");
    return -1;
  }

  if (listen(socketfd, 16)!=0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "listen error\n");
    return -1;
  }

  /* accept client */
  while (1)
  {
    socklen_t size = sizeof(address);
    int clientSocket = accept(socketfd, (struct sockaddr*) &address, &size);

    puts("client connected");

    if (fork() == 0)
    {
      write(clientSocket, header, strlen(header));
      write(clientSocket, buffer, bufferSize);
      exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
      close(clientSocket);
    }
  }

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc < 3 || argc > 3)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "needs 2 arguments: file path & port\n");
    return -1;
  }
  char *filepath = argv[1];
  int port = atoi(argv[2]);

  printf("serving %s on port %d\n"
       "file name(not path) cannot exceed 512 characters\n"
         "keyboard interrupt to kill\n", filepath, port);
  serveFile(filepath, port);
}
```

Comment: You are implementing HTTP, although you don't say so anywhere in your question.

Comment: `write` really needs an error check and it really needs to handle incomplete operations. Remember that `write` writes **up to** the number of bytes, but it can also write less (especially on slower network connections)...

Comment: @Myst So do you mean `write` does not guarantee that all the bytes are sent over? But I thought TCP is reliable. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @YuanFu, [read the `man` page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write). `write` reliably sends the number of bytes that it returned (i.e., if `write` returns 100, you know 100 bytes were sent). TCP/IP drivers have a limited buffer. Your program is expected to stream the data into the TCP/IP socket, managing any buffer data that couldn't be sent. Note that the word "reliable" is relative, and a reliable `send` doesn't promise a `recv`.

Comment: You're not implementing ranges at all. So why are you sending an `Accept-ranges` header? You need a good knowledge of RFC 2616 and successors to implement HTTP. You have a lot of reading to do.

Comment: @Myst It can only write less in blocking mode if there was an interrupt. But it certainly needs an error check, as do all the other system calls in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
12/23 20:04:07 [ERROR] CUID#8 - Download aborted. URI=http://104.38.127.225:8000
Exception: [AbstractCommand.cc:351] errorCode=8 URI=http://104.38.127.225:8000
   -> [HttpResponse.cc:86] errorCode=8 Invalid range header. Request: 98304-187031/187032, Response: 0-187031/187032
```

The error you attaches said it all, really.

Your code assumes that every request made to the server is a request asking for the whole of the file.

For many good reasons, this isn't always the case (*see edit*).

`Range` requests ([using the `Range` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests)) allow clients to request a part of the file, which allows breaking the download into chunks and resume downloads even after network failures.

However, your code also sends the whole file, regardless of the request made.

Moreover, your code is sending the `Accept-Ranges` header, indicating that Range requests will be respected (even though the aren't).

In this case, the client is complaining about your code, indicating it requested a chunk and your code sent the whole thing.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @RemyLebeau, [the `Range` function is optional, though widely used](http://httpwg.org/specs/).

This is why you only receive the error sometimes...

`aria2c` seems to require the range functionality to a degree, or it wouldn't be able to work as a download manager (managing downloads is the purpose of `Range` functionality, after all).

Other downloading tools will not require (or leverage) this functionality.

Comment: Just because a client sends a `Range` request doesn't mean the server is required to honor it. The client can differentiate between a partial file response (206) and a whole file response (200). A server sending back `Accept-Ranges` but not actually implementing ranges is not fatal, though it is not advisable, either. If the client is failing because the server sends 200 instead of 206 for a range request, then the client has a logic bug. Sending 200 is allowed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, you are correct. However , in this specific case, the question relates also to `aria2c`, which is a download manager that leverages (and seems to require) `Range` requests.

Comment: if a download manager can't handle a server that doesn't implement ranges, then it is not a very good download manager. In this situation, most download managers I have ever used will just ignore the first X bytes until they reach the desired offset, and then drop the connection after saving Y number of bytes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - the server written by the OP publishes that it does handle `Range` requests (Maybe my answer wasn't clear enough about this issue)... I think this conflict in behavior is an issue in the code. Besides, I'm no `aria2c` follower. If you think it's a bad download manage, that's fine by me. I agree that a better download manager might degrade more gracefully. On the other hand, if the server doesn't support `Range` requests, no download manager is required, since there's no way to recover from errors without restarting the download (making the download manager mostly redundant).